# VBA function assigns empty string instead of range value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following function to look through column 1 of a table (`rngSearch`) and return the corresponding value in column 2, basically mirroring the functionality of `VLOOKUP`. It generally works as intended, except for when it doesn't. It sometimes returns a `vbNullString` instead of the desired string value.

```
Function get_short_string(rngSearch As Range, strSearch As String) As String

    get_short_string = vbNullString

    For i = 1 To rngSearch.Rows.Count
        If LCase(rngSearch(1)(i)) = LCase(strSearch) Then
            get_short_string = rngSearch(2)(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

I've stepped through the function and narrowed it down to this line:

```
get_short_string = rngSearch(2)(i)
```

When I enter `? rngSearch(2)(i)` into the immediate window at that point I get the desired output string. When I then execute the line `get_short_string` gets assigned a `vbNullString`. At least that's what I think it is, when I hover the mouse over `get_short_string` after executing the line the tooltip shows `get_short_string =` without the empty string `""`. I've also tried `rngSearch(2)(i).Value` and `rngSearch(2)(i).Value2` with the same result.

EDIT: Thank you for the answers. The problem seems to be not in the code but with the strings being handled. I will replace this custom function with VlookUp and investigate further.

EDIT2: As requested here is a sample of the tablein its original german form:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
|                Internes Projekt nach CRM                 |     Kurzname     |
+----------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| Urlaub | geplante Abwesenheit 2020                       | URLAUB           |
| Interne Projekte 2020                                    | INTERNE PROJEKTE |
| Akquise 2020                                             | AKQUISE          |
| Unterstützung (nicht fakturierbar) anderer Projekte 2020 | andere           |
| Verwaltung | Arbeitsorganisation 2020                    | VERWALTUNG       |
| Interne Projekte 2019                                    | INTERNE PROJEKTE |
| Unterstützung Team (intern)                              | andere           |
+----------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

When looking for the exact string in row 2 `Urlaub | geplante Abwesenheit 2020` the code identifies row 2 correctly. When I use the immediate window `? rngSearch(2)(i)` it outputs `URLAUB`, but the function returns an empty variable.

Comment: I think answer below should help but for my own curiosity, why don't you just use `VlookUp`?

Comment: Care to share some of your string values? Curious to know where your comparison goes wrong. What comes to mind are trailing/leading spaces or other unseen characters.

Comment: @JvdV It's not the comparison that goes wrong, it identifies the correct row, but when the corresponding value is assigned to the function output, the function output is always empty.

Comment: I'm intriged. Please share your sample data and let me know on what exact value the returned value gives your `vbNullSting` =). Replicating your issue might be key here.

Comment: @JvdV Second edit :) It's worth noting that using `Application.Vlookup` produces the same result.

Comment: Your current UDF worked perfectly fine for me on your sample data. Can you share your sample workbook? It's usually not-done but there must be something rather simple going on here.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks for your interest, but sadly I'm not allowed to share it since it's from work and there is too much sensitive data in it to take out. I'll keep investigating it and report back if I find anything. The UDF also works fine for me in most cases, only that specific one breaks it.

Comment: I understand, but if you can represent it in a meaningless sample that still returns the empty string it could be fine. Up to you. Good luck nonetheless =)

Comment: @JvdV After playing around a bit (only meaningless stuff like changing the order of the table data), the problem has suddenly disappeared and is no longer reproducable. VBA gives me headaches sometimes. I've now changed everything to Vlookup and its still working correctly. Btw it's always fun seeing you on here, always respectful and constructive, keep it up!

Comment: The "problem" probably originated from the way you define `strSearch`. In your system this must be done with a drop-down. If, in testing, you tried to enter the string manually any typo would cause your function to return vbNullString. Same, of course, if the drop-down list contained a typo.

Comment: I just emerged from a battle with a similar problem  Stepping though an "array function", code saw a "vbNullString" in an array of cells passed in as an argument.  In the Immediate window ?array(n).value would show the expected string.  I think the problem was that code sees the updated worksheet, while the visible worksheet is not updated until the worksheet has been updated.  The immediate window sees that same not-updated sheet.  Erroneous code put the null string in a cell.  With that error fixed, the disparity disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't pinpoint where, exactly, your code goes wrong but the function below is both clearer in syntax and more robust in execution. I don't think it will give you the same kind of error.

```
Function GetShortString(rngSearch As Range, _
                        strSearch As String) As String

    Dim R As Long

    With rngSearch
        For R = 1 To .Rows.Count
            If StrComp(.Cells(R, 1).Value, strSearch, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                GetShortString = .Cells(R, 2).Value
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next R
    End With
End Function
```

However, looping through a range takes time. If speed is of interest to you use the function below instead.

```
Function ShortString(rngSearch As Range, _
                     strSearch As String) As String
    ShortString = Application.VLookup(strSearch, rngSearch, 2, False)
End Function
```

Comment: Up voted as i think `VlookUp` is probably a better option

Comment: VlookUp is definitely the better option here, I still run into the same problem with it though. I'm starting to think it is something about the search string or the resulting string that causes this. I am absolutely clueless what is going on, I will have top play around with it some more. As to why I didn't use VlookUp in the first place: I was not even thinking about WorksheetFunctions until I typed the question above and by that time I was so interested in this weird malfunction that I was looking for an answer anyway. I will change the code to VlookUp, you're right!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `option compare text` to compare case-insensitive, try this code:

```
Option Compare Text  
Function get_short_string(rngSearch As Range, strSearch As String) As String   
        For i = 1 To rngSearch.Rows.Count
            If rngSearch.Cells(i, 1) = strSearch Then
                get_short_string = rngSearch.Cells(i, 2): Exit Function
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    get_short_string = "not found"
    End Function
```

or:

> ```
> Function get_short_string(rngSearch As Range, strSearch As String) As String
>     Dim index As Variant: index = Application.Match(strSearch, rngSearch.Columns(1), 0)
>     get_short_string = IIf(IsError(index), "not found", rngSearch.Cells(index, 2))
> End Function
> ```

Comment: You could also use `vbTextCompare` in `InStr` to achieve the same results

Comment: Thank you for your input! Sadly it doesn't address / solve my problem, I get the same result with your code. The code finds the correct row and string value to assign, it simply doesn't assign the string to `get_short_string` and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: @Zac not approxiate match! , schalk:  Make sure they are the same, I think you are in excess of space in or something. checked by operator "="